# To Shrink or Not to Shrink the Log File

Tags: logging, sql-server-2012, backup, filesize, shrink

As a fairly new DBA, I have a question for the experts out there.  We have a database transaction log file that grew to a whopping 425 GB because no transaction log backups were taking place (the db backup plan is set to full recovery mode.)  I have since remedied the problem, and the t-logs are being backed up regularly now.  The backups are all coming in at around 6.5 GB, but the original log file is still 425 GB.

Obviously, we need to shrink the size of the original file.  I have read a lot of comments about how shrinking the file could cause performance problems, so before I shrink it, I wanted to ask if there are any hidden repercussions I need to be aware of.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Definitely a question for [dba.se]

Comment: Thanks Mike.  You are right.  This is the first question I have ever tried to post on stackoverflow.  How do I move my question to the appropriate site?

Comment: Sorry to say, the only way I know is to copy and paste it. It'll probably be migrated eventually, but that will need another four votes.

Comment: I will just copy and paste it.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.